# I want to remove maven dependency from a spring project. I am using netbeans

Tags: maven, web

I have created a maven based spring project. Now I want to remove pom.xml file and want to manage jars by myself. I want further jars to be downloaded straight away from web rather than maven. When I remove pom.xml then project stops compiling. Can I remove maven from my project ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the **pom.xml** (in Project Files) and and in the *XML source* search the `<dependency>`. Remove the XML part.